# calc between points in django postgis

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, postgis

i have a model:

```
class lctnp(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    pin = gmodel.PointField(geography=True, null=True, srid=4326)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']
```

and input with:

```
{
        "id": "",
        "owner": "1",
        "pin": "POINT(-95.3385 29.7245)",
        "description": "hello from here"
    }
```

and try to calc distance with another point:

```
query = '''
        SELECT id,
            ST_Transform(pin, 4326),
            ST_Distance(pin, 'SRID=26918;POINT(-95.3385 30.7245)') AS dist
        FROM
            house_lctnp
        ORDER BY
            pin <-> 'SRID=26918;POINT(-95.3385 30.7245)'::geometry
        LIMIT 3;
    '''
    for p in lctnp.objects.raw(query):
        return JsonResponse(p.description, safe=False)
```

but seems i try a wrong way. plz help me

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: find all house_lctnp row that in range of static point

Comment: It would be much easier if you could add the sample data and the exact expected result to your question. The actual result set, not its description.